# Path to a root file in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

1. Can you store a `.pem` as an environment variable? If so, how?
2. How can I access my `.pem` from from the controller?

**Controller:**

```
before_filter :some_method

def show
  @some_var = @data
end

private
  def some_method
    @data = Some::PrivateApplication.new(ENV['KEY1'], "../../secret.pem")
  end
```

**Views:**

```
<%= @som_var.SOMECONST.some_other_method %>
```

> No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - ../../secret.pem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the hash `ENV` for environment variables, e.g.

```
ENV['SECRET_PEM_FILE']
```

To find the path relative to your application, try `Rails.root`, e.g.

```
"#{Rails.root}/config/secret.pem"
```

...but don't put the key in version control!

Comment: Thank you. I forgot about `Rails.root`